# droid-wrapper, agcc with x86, mips or similar script

Tags: android-ndk, android-source

It seems these projects do not update and they are missing x86 and mips support.

Are they dead?

Tor for Android is build with [droid-wrapper](https://github.com/tmurakam/droid-wrapper).
I am willing to compile Tor for android-x86.
(Right now Tor for android has no x86 support.)

I have setup AOSP, droid-wrapper and I build it for ARM.

If I will modify droid-wrapper myself to work for x86 then do I have to use another AOSP folder?

I downloaded AOSP

```
lunch # select generic
make -j4
```

so may be I need another AOSP folder

```
lunch # select generic_86
make -j4
```

Not sure if I need another folder to build for second platform.

Such a great tool with no documentation at all.